# How to aggregate mongodb data by matching a value in object array using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose, aggregate

Hi I have the below data in mongodb

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64ca10afd4b19833b87298d4"
  },
  "orderId": "597628170576",
   "items": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64ca10b2d4b19833b87298d7"
      },
      "item_id": "ITEM_004",
      "title": "Sampoo",
      "subtotal": 28,
      "total": 30.32,
      "tax": 2.32,
      "discount": 20
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64ca10afd4b19833b87298d4"
  },
  "orderId": "597628170576",
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64ca10b2d4b19833b87298d7"
      },
      "item_id": "ITEM_004",
      "title": "Sampoo",
      "quantity": 4,
      "tax": 2.32,
      "discount": 20
    }
  ]

}
```

I have a requirement where i have to match items.tax >0 and display

Below is the aggregation that i tried

```
model.aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              item: {
                $elemMatch: {
                  tax: { $gt: 0 }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
        ])
```

But this seems to give me null value, kindly let me know how to proceed further

Answer (score 0):

After your edit I noticed the items are indeed nested, given so, the problem could be that the attribute is "items" (in plural) while you are looking into an attribute that doesn't exist called "item".

so this should work:

```
model.aggregate([
  {
     $match: {
       items: {
          $elementMatch: {
            tax: { $gt: 0 }
          }
       }
     }
  },
  { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

Or shorter:

```
model.aggregate([
  {
     $match: {
       "items.tax": { $gt: 0 }
     }
  },
  { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

More information here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#examples